# Issue Implementing ImageBubbles in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement this JQuery ImageBubbles that I found here:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagebubbles.htm

However, I have some type of an error within my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/hbMzV/1/

If someone could clue me in on my error, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the js/css, add this to the top of your html ...

```html
<script src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imgbubbles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imgbubbles.css" />
```

Here's one I prepared earlier ... http://jsfiddle.net/hbMzV/2/

This is just to get it working in the jsfiddle. If you were to use this on your own site you would simply have to download the css/js files provided by dynamicdrive and host them on your own site, fixing up the Uris appropriately

Comment: since I cant get this to work in IE8 for the Fiddle, do you think it would work on a site with IE?

Comment: Try visiting the dynamicdrive page first, your browser will then cache the js and css, then visit the jsfiddler in my answer and it should work. So, if you host those files on the same server as your site, then it should be fine. I'm guessing the IE8 issue may be down the the markup and/or doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug shows that the script cannot be downloaded correctly, returning a `403 forbidden` for `imgbubbles.js` (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imgbubbles.js), hence resulting in the error:

```
$("ul#orbs").imgbubbles is not a function
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NinjaSk8ter/hbMzV/1/show/
Line 58
```

Comment: its there, so how can I remedy this?

Comment: @Paul, it looks like dynamicdrive does not allow referrers from outside of their own domain, so you would remedy this by hosting the file elsewhere, or copying the contents of the file into your fiddle.

Comment: try clicking the link in my answer, it works. or at least it does for me. whereas the jsfiddle link in your question is missing the script/link tags to the js/css on dynamicdrive.

Comment: I guess my browser could have cached it.

Comment: @AntonyScott I think the browser has cached it... Or maybe not. Your fiddle works for me too, so I don't really know what to think. Because Firebug also displays the 403 error for your fiddle, but it does work none the less.

Comment: I just tried it in another browser and I got a script error complaining about imgbubbles being undefined, so I guess the first browser I tried it in had already cached it when I looked at the original article on dynamicdrive. CONFIRMED ... visit the dynamic drive page first, then it will work in the jsfiddle.